# Does anyone know a simple way to set x/y position on a fixed size pop up rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I need to have a simple pop up rectangle, preferably with jQuery or some such, that simply brings up a scaled down canvas (say, 1:2, representing a 1000px x 1600px browser window) that can be clicked on to get the x/y position in the full window.

It's really just a simple, visual way to help a client position content on a page (it has to be completely at their control, not on a grid).

Does anyone have an idea of something out there that already does something like this? (I'm looking for the wordpress admin, but should be able to work anything in pretty much).

Edit to clarify. Here is what I'm thinking might work if there is nothing out there that does this:

If you click a button, jQ an absolute positioned div (lightbox style), of the sized I talked about, then close the div upon clicking it, but somehow get the x/y position in the div where it was clicked and then scale this with some maths...

I think the thing I don't know how to do here is getting the x/y position relative to the size of the specific div.

Sorry, I think this is maybe a bit of a terribly worded question.

Comment: I'm not the best at jQ etc so I was kind of hoping there might be a library that someone knew :/ I can't really think of what to search for. (see above for edits on what I'm thinking)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#popup').css("top", ($(window).height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
$('#popup').css("left", ($(window).width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

your canva need to be set to

```
position: relative
```

then anything inside this element can be set to

```
position : absolute
top:  [your Y position from top side of the canva]px;
left: [your X position from left side of the canva]px;
```

Absolute position always refers to the first element that has no default positionning, in this case relative.